# Are polygons created in Arcpy built in any order?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, arcgis-desktop

My script uses a search cursor to evaluate polyline coordinates and build polygons based on those coordinates.  The script works well, but I am curious as to whether anyone knows the order (if there is any) that polygons are built.  I know that the output polygon feature class reads the rows (and their coordinates) in order, but I do not know if they *build* them in order.  I could see the polygons being built according to which order they were read, or based on size, etc.  Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't your question "does a search cursor read rows in any order"? Since that is how you are building the polygons. And the answer to that would be "it depends".

Comment: My question isn't necessarily that.  I would assume that a search cursor *reads* the rows in order based on and FID or ObjectID field for reasons of operational simplicity.  However, because the polygons created are only derived from information gathered by the search cursor (not related to them by any attribute or ID field) I am wondering if they take that same course of action when being built and exported or if they are built/exported at random.

Comment: I think you'll need to post your code because I'm not getting the full picture. How exactly are you creating the polygons?

Comment: Also what prompted you to ask this question? I.e. is there some other problem you are trying to solve that this ties into?